# Business forms automation options Decision

Tags: webforms, systems-analysis, business-process

There is this situation

We have many business paper forms that needs to be turned into web based Forms with approval workflows

Well we have a small development team (2 developers) who are also responsible for all other in-house developed applications.

Which leaves us with these options:

1. To develop each form as a web application (or each set of related forms into an application)
2. To Use Workflow creation tool (Nintex or Power forms) and assign junior team members or user support team members to create the form

Now option 1 is more preferred by me but with limited team and limited time (there are other projects, plus support and maintenance to already live applications ) we will need longer time than what the business expects the form be ready in.

Option 2 should be easier to do and faster (may be our paper forms are more complicated than normal , or business expectations from automation is complicated) but resources assigned to do so even with support from the development team not able to move fast enough even on single form

How should the Technical lead decide on the way forward in this situation ? Business prefers all forms automated to be in similar enviroment and look and feel so i guess we need to select one option for all forms but non of the options seems to work?

Answer (score 1):

### Create two [**spikes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike_(software_development)) for the same form - one with each technology.

That will allow you to gather experience with the approaches, hopefully enough to decide which one will suit your organization most. Sometimes the most effective option is to invest some time into a time-boxed experiment.

Comment: Sir thank you for introducing me to the spikes concept ,  still doing so will require both teams and both technologies but  that will be for one of the forms only and will give us clear direction, now hope higher managment will understand this is to save time later and selection of best way forward, hope they will not think it is redundant use of resources and an extra delay